# How do I exit an entire multithreaded Rust program program immediately when some thread panics?

Tags: error-handling, rust

Preferably all the file descriptors will be closed properly. Is `std::panic::set_hook` the right way?

The program is a server side app, and if something panics there is something very wrong. I don’t use panic in my code, and it's not something that is considered during development, so it would be hard to have confidence that it will be caught and recovered correctly. Instead of trying to catch the error and try to recover, I want to crash and restart, the Erlang way.